# Accessing data from a dictionary in python and raw_input formatting

Tags: python

For this program I need to use raw-input to tell the program which bible verse I would like to read.I have to be able to use, for instance these formats gen 1 , gen 1:1 , and finally gen 1:1-10 to bring the selected data up for viewing I tried to do this with but it will always say that the list has been exceeded.

```
 bibletext = open("kjv.txt" , "r").readlines()
 main = raw_input('')
 a = main.split()
 b = a[2].split(":")
 c = b[1].split("-")

 bible = {}
 for line in bibletext:
     number,bv,contents = line.split(" | ")
     book,ver = bv.strip().split(" ")
     chapter,verse = ver.strip().split(":")
     if book == a[1] and chapter == b[0] and verse == b[1]:
       print "%s , %s , %s" % (number, bv, contents)
```

here is a sample of the txt file that we must use.

```
0 | gen 1:1 | In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth. 
1 | gen 1:2 | And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters. 
2 | gen 1:3 | And God said, Let there be light: and there was light. 
3 | gen 1:4 | And God saw the light, that it was good: and God divided the light from the darkness. 
4 | gen 1:5 | And God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night. And the evening and the morning were the first day. 
5 | gen 1:6 | And God said, Let there be a firmament in the midst of the waters, and let it divide the waters from the waters. 
6 | gen 1:7 | And God made the firmament, and divided the waters which were under the firmament from the waters which were above the firmament: and it was so. 
7 | gen 1:8 | And God called the firmament Heaven. And the evening and the morning were the second day. 
8 | gen 1:9 | And God said, Let the waters under the heaven be gathered together unto one place, and let the dry land appear: and it was so. 
9 | gen 1:10 | And God called the dry land Earth; and the gathering together of the waters called he Seas: and God saw that it was good. 
10 | gen 1:11 | And God said, Let the earth bring forth grass, the herb yielding seed, and the fruit tree yielding fruit after his kind, whose seed is in itself, upon the earth: and it was so.
```

Answer (score 0):

its becuase if use gen 1:1 as input and you print `a` you get `['gen', '1:1']`

which means there is no `a[2]` just `a[0]` and `a[1]`

so if you try and use `a[2]` you will get an error saying list index out of range

so instead do:

```
b = a[1].split(":")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code, which will accept requests in the form of "`gen 1:1`" or "`gen 1:3-5`":

```
main = raw_input('')
a = main.split(" ")
b = a[1].split(":")
c = b[1].split("-")
verses = c[0] if len(c) == 1 else range(int(c[0]),int(c[1])+1)

bible = {}
for line in bibletext.splitlines():
    number,bv,contents = line.split(" | ")
    book,ver = bv.strip().split(" ")
    chapter,verse = ver.strip().split(":")
    for i in verses:
        if book == a[0].strip() and chapter == b[0].strip() and verse == str(i):
            print "%s, %s" % (bv, contents)
```

Comment: Thank you but I keep getting a error that reads AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'splitlines'

Comment: Once again, you'll need to remove the ".splitlines()" if you're feeding it a file that's already been "`.readlines()`"-ed.